# Примет ли сообщество вопрос по теме учебных материалов Fortran?

Tags: обсуждение, учебные-материалы

Хочу задать вопрос на ruSO, вопрос по теме Фортрана (язык программирования), а точнее по теме его учебных материалов. Я сам не нашёл на ruSO вопрос по типу того который хочу задать. Я просмотрел много вопросов в Мете (русской) насчёт вопросов с учебными материалами и остались смешанные эмоции, я так и не понял примет ли сообщество новый вопрос с неизвестным языком программирования или нет.

Comment: язык известный - вот наличие книжек/документации может быть вопросом.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, что отозвались! Буду публиковать вопрос!

Comment: @Grundy только вот ещё вопрос, а можно ли использовать метку "книги" на мой вопрос, т.к. в этой метке написано, что её нельзя использовать, т.к. уже есть материалы, но там нет того что я хочу.

Comment: @NNL993, в подробном описании метки есть строка: _Не создавайте новых вопросов, если по вашей теме уже есть вопрос в этом списке._

Comment: @ΝNL993 книги можно сделать. Но, замечу, вопрос и ответ на это все всегда делают общими, типа такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609900/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос я не делал общий так как забыл, а вот когда делал ответ, всё сделал правильно!

Comment: Можно модеров попросить сконвертировать)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это делается как я понимаю по типу **Тревога > Требуется вмешательство модератора**?